# Generate part-random strings from regex

Tags: r

I have a set of complex identifiers that are the column names of a dataframe. This regular expression matches all of them :

```
regex <- "^PLUTO-.{2}-.{4}-01.{1}-.{3}-.{4}-.{2}$"
```

Now I would like to generate random identifiers using this regex to get something like this :

```
"PLUTO-xx-xxxx-01x-xxx-xxxx-xx"
"PLUTO-xx-xxxx-01x-xxx-xxxx-xx"
...
```

Where x's are random characters.

Is there a function that does such things in R? I found such topics for java and python but nothing in R (only paste() and collapse() solutions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsub("\\^|\\$", "", gsubfn("\\.{([[:digit:]]+)}", ~ paste(rep("x", n), collapse=""), regex))
#[1] "PLUTO-xx-xxxx-01x-xxx-xxxx-xx"
```

Comment: Thanks your code with `rep(sample(c(LETTERS, 1:9), 1), n)` did the trick! Though I was thinking about a function that would identify regex and randomly generate possible strings.